# Make user friendly url with .htaccess and php

Tags: php, url

I want to make User Friendly Url for my website with .HTTACCESS

This default my URL

```
domain/?p=news-details&id=4
```

I Want to like this

```
domain/news-details/4
```

This is what I have so far, but it is not working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule //(.*)$ /?p=news-details&id=$1
```

thanks for responded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

If your ID is always an integer you can do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^news-details/([0-9]+)$ phpPage.php?p=news-details&id=$1 [L]
```

Where `([0-9]+)` is a pattern that matches a group of 1 or more numbers from 0 to 9.

`[L]` means if the rule matches, don't process any more RewriteRules below this one.

Comment: Thanks For responded xyzale 
still the same, no changes

Comment: If its not an integer?

Comment: If it's not an integer you need to apply a proper regex, like for example `([a-z0-9_-]+)` in order to allow lowercase letters numbers, dashes and underscores.

Comment: @Novry check my latest changes, I added the php file meant to be executed.

Comment: ok @xyzale I've implemented a new scritpt, but it still does not work, this script `RewriteRule ^news-details/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=news-details&id=$1 [L]`

Comment: Check I wrote news-details rather than news-detail, your url wants to be singular but the get var is plural, I edited the answer now

Comment: i'm sorry @xyzale, i mean news-details not news-detail, I have edited but still doesn't work

Comment: @Novry I have a doubt ... you wrote .HTTACCESS, be sure the file is .htaccess with one T